# how change url character with 301 redirect in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

i want to use 301 redirect for change url that contain "Product" to "product" (difference is in p)
i use this code in page_load of page

```
 if (urlAddress.Contains("products"))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            Response.StatusCode = 301;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.ToString().Replace("products", "Products"));
            Response.End();
        }
```

but after redirecting again this condition is true and i go in a loop
how can change "P" to "p" in URL

Comment: did you make URL case sensitive?

Comment: no, www.domain.com/page1 is equal with www.domain.com/Page1  but google see two diffrenet page

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by using `UrlRewrite`,

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
             <rule name="LowerCaseRule">
              <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false"/>
              <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}"/>
             </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @user2399248 please vote up if this answer is helpful. thanks